# Error while trying to install Ubuntu 20.04LTS alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, error-handling

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04LTS alongside windows 10 but my Dell gaming laptop crashes and a black screen appears with the following error:

```
sd 3:0:0:0:tag#0 access beyond end of device
blk_update_request:I/O error, dev sea, sector 60948352 op 0x0
sd 3:0:0:0:tag#0 access beyond end of device
blk_update_request:I/O error,dev sea, sector 60948352 op 0x0
Buffer I/O error on dev sea, logical block 7618544, async page read
DRM: failed to idle channel 1 [DRM]
```

I follow every instruction in the following youtube video but nothing works.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSVV_EoApdo&t=258s

Any thoughts?

Comment: It would be good to list the  things you tried, because people with limited bandwidth wont watch a video.

Comment: Also please attach a partition table.  It would help to see how your drive is partitioned.  Best from a Gparted Live CD/USB